# How to load external module Powershell in Azure webjobs

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-webjobs

I want to run a PowerShell script on Azure webjobs and I need to install SharePointPnPPowerShellOnline module in Azure Webjobs for my business but I can't install external modules. I also try to config 'modules' files like Azure function but It's not working.
How I can use the Install-Module or something is equivalent in Azure Webjobs?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Not sure if this will help, but you can [add a location to the PSModulePath variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/developer/module/modifying-the-psmodulepath-installation-path?view=powershell-7#to-add-locations-to-the-psmodulepath-variable)

Comment: Tks it really helpful! You safe my day

Comment: How you have resolved this issue can you share your thoughts? I didn't understand from comment.

Comment: You can see my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To load external modules in Azure Webjob. We need to access SCM then choose some directory and put modules into your directory

Finally using apply this code

```
$MyModulePath="yourPath"
$env:PSModulePath = $env:PSModulePath + "$([System.IO.Path]::PathSeparator)$MyModulePath"
```